# OS for Eee PC 4G Surf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, eee-pc

I have an Eee PC 4G Surf, which I have not used for more than a year. My mothers netbook just broke and I was thinking to activate this device for her. However, I want to know what OS to install on it.

The requirements are very basic:

- She needs to have internet connection (so wifi and network adapter must be recognized)
- A good browser (chrome, ff or similar)
- A basic video player and picture browser

I had installed Ubuntu netbook remix previously on the device, however it failed to play videos correctly (e.g., they would freeze, flicker etc)

Any ideas? I have heard about meego, android for eee-pc and even windows xp. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same device and right now I'm using Arch Linux with xfce. Any number of browsers would run and for videos I use VLC. 
At one point android was running on it, and while fast was very non-intuitive and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Arch Linux or Debian: the two can be made into very small distros with good performance even for smaller machines.

But then, disconsider KDE and GNOME; probably XFCE should work well. [This tutorial](http://www.leduotang.com/sylvain/node/178)  has a set of recommended packages. Also, even if you don't go with Arch, the ArchWiki entry for the [EEE PC](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Eee_PC_701) has a lot of good recommendations.

Windows XP might be feasible, too. (In fact, might be the best choice if your mother doesn't want the learning curve of a Linux environment)

Comment: I will consider installing Arch Linux. Though I find the process cumbersome. On the other hand, as far as I can see this distro is not much suitable for small screen netbooks.

Comment: You will have to do adaptations with pretty much any distro; most of the default themes in most distros aren't designed for small screens.